# How can I install desktop VPN (not extensions) for Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: apt, package-management, google-chrome, vpn, brave

I'm trying to install a VPN for my Ubuntu 21.04.

As our government has banned so many websites, I really need it.

I can install extensions for my browsers (brave/chrome) because the chrome store hasn't been banned (So I can install VPN in the browser).

But with browser extensions, I can't access other applications out of the browser, For example, I can't use Telegram Desktop (It has been banned).

So I decided to install ProtonVPN.

First I turned on my browser VPN([protonVPN](https://protonvpn.com/) is banned too), then I went to [protonvpn.com](https://protonvpn.com/)
and downloaded the .deb file.

I went through all the steps as it said: https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-ubuntu-vpn-setup/
but I wasn't able to pass the last step(sudo apt-get install protonvpn) As I said their website is banned.

Terminal says :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package protonvpn
```

So I downloaded the .exe file (because with just running the file I can install it on my system)
But in the installation process, it gives me lots of errors. (I did it by wine)

Do you have any solutions?

Also, Do you know which FREE VPNs are able to install just by clicking on the .deb file

Help Please!

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop includes a *built-in* PPTP VPN client. You don't need to install anything. Choose a VPN provider that does not require you to download their own client.

Comment: Have you tried openvpn?

Comment: Why are you trying install Protonvpn and Telegram if they've been banned in your country? They obviously don't want encrypted software to work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the ProtonVPN repository is missing.

Check if the ProtonVPN repo is actually installed.
The output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/protonvpn-stable.list` should have this line:

> deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/protonvpn-stable-archive-keyring.gpg] https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable main

If it's not presenet, try adding the ProtonVPN repository again.

1. Download the .deb file by ProtonVPN which adds it's repository to your apt sources list.

   `wget https://protonvpn.com/download/protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.1-1_all.deb`
2. Instal the downloaded file with
   `sudo dpkg -i protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.1-1_all.deb`
3. Update your package list in apt with `sudo apt update`

   If adding the repository was successful, you should see something like this in the output of the `apt update` command:

   > Get:7 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable/main all Packages [25.1 kB]`

*Note: Version numbers of the ProtonVPN .deb package may change in the future, please replace it with the current version, which you can find at https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-ubuntu-vpn-setup/*

Comment: I can't add the repository because the website is banned.

Comment: Then try using https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-openvpn/ as it doesn't require any external repositories. However, if the website is blocked, it might be possible, that their servers are also blocked. If they are, try using Tor with bridges.

Comment: I had a bunch of issues, deleted the sources.list reference to protonvpn, removed the GPG keys, now when I download the dev file and try to install, it does not add anything to sources.list or keys. Any ideas on how to get access back to the repo?

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe try to install it in a clean VM with nothing changed after installation. You may be able to learn something about the issue that way. If the installer works in the VM, than your system is misconfigured (somehow), if it doesn't work in the VM, than the problem is not with your system, but with something else.